# Can the help page be updated?

Tags: discussion, support

Critique requests have been off-topic on Writers for some time now. Today, I was looking at [this site's help pages](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and came across this:

> This is **not** the right site for questions about:
>
> - Writing advice or critique requests - see [writers.stackexchange.com](https://writers.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Thanks for sending us questions about writing, that's great! But could someone please edit this page so it no longer directs critique requests to our site?

Comment: I'm sure we can manage that. Perhaps if you could give us a brief recommendation of what you guys would prefer it say?

Comment: Yes I agree that the 'see [writers.se] part' should be removed, but what else should we put there? We need to recommend them an alternative way to make sure they won't hit us.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M Why remove "see writers"? Why not simply remove "critique requests"?

Comment: @Cat we occasionally do get writing advice questions. We should have something in the [help] to point to when they ask why we close their question as writing advice.

Comment: @Catija Maybe remove "critique requests" from this statement? You could break it out into its own statement.

Comment: Hmm, that could work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely, I'd be happy to make that change for you. Can you please leave a comment with the description you'd like us to give for appropriate Writers questions?

Comment: How about simply changing the above to: "This is not the right site for questions about: Writing advice - see writers.stackexchange.com instead"

Comment: @neilfein Done!